# Extract images from SWF file

Tags: c#, image, flash, extract

Is it possible to programmatically extract image files from a SWF file using C#? If so, how would I go about doing that? I know this question doesn't have a lot of detail but I'm just getting started on this and know very little about Flash. Just need some direction on how to go about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this SWfDotNet flash decompiler library 
[SWfDotNet](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/swfdotnet-decompiler.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

check [swf file format spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf), Bitmaps, from page 147